# Duas actions em um mesmo form

Tags: javascript, formulário

Olá! Preciso ter duas actions em um mesmo form. Pesquisei algumas soluções e fiz da seguinte forma:

```
<form id="formnewsletter" name="formnewsletter" method="POST">

   <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

   <button type="button" onClick="enviaForm();">Enviar</button>

<script>
function enviaForm(){
    document.getElementById('formnewsletter').action = 'form_newsletter.php';
    document.getElementById('formnewsletter').submit();

    document.getElementById('formnewsletter').action = 'https://www.rdstation.com.br/api/1.2/conversions';
    document.getElementById('formnewsletter').submit();
}
</script>

</form>
```

O problema é que ele só dispara a segunda action, se eu inverter a posição das actions, então a outra fica sem funcionar. Como poderia corrigir isso? Com Ajax seria melhor?

Desde já obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui fazer o form enviar para duas actions. Se alguém precisar, segue o código abaixo:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function enviaForm(nome,email){
            $.ajax(
                    {
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "form_newsletter.php",
                      data: "&nome="+nome+"&email="+email,
                      beforeSend: function() {
                      },
                      success: function(txt) {
                        if(txt.status=='success')
                            alert("E-mail cadastrado com sucesso!\n\nObrigado!");
                        else
                            alert("E-mail não cadastrado.");

                            EnviaForm2();
                      },
                      error: function(txt) {
                      }
                    }
                );

        }


        function EnviaForm2()
        {
            document.getElementById('formnewsletter').action = 'https://www.rdstation.com.br/api/1.2/conversions';
            document.getElementById('formnewsletter').submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

O seu código fará o POST para apenas uma das duas URLs, e depois será redirecionado para a página que o formulário foi enviado. Veja [este exemplo](http://jsbin.com/karehahuzera/1/edit?html,js,output).

Quando você usa `.submit()` em js o navegador irá fazer a requisição POST e redirecionar para a página em que o formulário foi enviado, como se o usuário tivesse clicado normalmente no submit do formulário.

No seu caso o melhor a ser feito é fazer as requisições com Ajax e depois mostrar uma mensagem para o usuário dizendo que ele foi inscrito nas duas newsletters. Em jQuery você pode usar [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/).

Comment: Amigo agradeço sua ajuda, mas não tenho um bom conhecimento com ajax. Por favor, poderia me mostrar como devo fazer com esse código? Obrigado!